# How do I write responseDecodable data with not getting errors?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire, codable

I have a problem with JSON response data access.

**Response** looks like this:

```
 {
    "q": "The less you try to impress, the more peaceful you can be.",
    "a": "Maxime Lagace",
    "h": "<blockquote>&ldquo;The less you try to impress, the more peaceful you can be.&rdquo; &mdash; <footer>Maxime Lagace</footer></blockquote>"
  }
```

**Сode** looks like this:

```
struct Quote: Decodable {
            var q: String
            var a: String
            var h: String
        }


AF.request(url).responseDecodable(of: Quote.self) { response in
            print(response) }
```

So when I try to print it I get the "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead" error. As a result - I can't get access to response data (response.value is nil).

I just need to write the response to my structure and use "q", "a", "h" variables.

Thank you.

Comment: the response is probably an array, so use `[Quote].self`

Comment: I tried to use [Quote].self but when i call `print(response.value![0])` I get `Quote(q: "What kills the creative force is not age or lack of talent, but our own spirit, our own attitude.",
a: "Robert Greene", 
h: "<blockquote>&ldquo;What kills the creative force is not age or lack of talent, but our own spirit, our own attitude.&rdquo; &mdash; <footer>Robert Greene</footer></blockquote>")`

So how to get access to each variable?

Comment: I need to get Strings out of it but have no idea how to do this :/

Comment: I am an idiot. Got fixed it